# How to use IN clause in Microsoft graph Api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have two team ids which I want to search in one query. I already tried some possible queries like one blow but nothing working

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team') and id eq ['13be6971-79db-4f33-9d41-b25589ca25af', '02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315]'

this is the error message that this query is giving 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ced5a7c7-73a1-49bb-afc1-3f312bac8759",
            "date": "2019-09-11T08:11:58"
        }
    }
}

To use graph API explorer you can click here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Answer (score 3):

Given that you use v1.0 api version instead of beta, then the IN query should be possible:

```
$filter=displayName in ('group-1', 'group-2')
```

Full url example after encoding:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName%20in%20%28%27group-1%27%2C%20%27group-2%27%29
```

Btw this was written by hand - I found no Microsoft documentation example how to build IN operator query.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` filter operator does not seem to be supported by Graph up to now, hence the error.  At least it is not mentioned to be supported in the [documentation](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x%20eq%20'Team')%20and%20id%20eq%20['13be6971-79db-4f33-9d41-b25589ca25af',%20'02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315]'):

> Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs. The following logical operators are generally supported:
>
> - equals (eq)
> - not equals (ne)
> - greater than (gt)
> - greater than or equals (ge)
> - less than (lt),
> - less than or equals (le)
> - and (and)
> - or (or)
> - not (not)

If you have a limited set of values for the in clause, you could use `eq` and `or`, e.g.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team') and (id eq '13be6971-79db-4f33-9d41-b25589ca25af' or id eq '02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315')
```

Comment: Thanks Markus! yes its working, we can use the same for in operator like 

<br>https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter= (id eq '67e08701-4d78-4086-a019-4b499a3ab57f' or id eq '5ab4b1ee-51fe-4c7c-9a36-6e1dd9636445')

Comment: Has anyone found out a working solution on how to use the `in` filter clause?

Comment: I have checked the documentation, and no proper solution found
The following is a description from the official documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#support-for-filter-on-properties-of-azure-ad-directory-objects
`The in operator is supported by default whenever eq operator is supported by default.`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter lists In as being supported, but I couldn't get to work in the Graph Explorer. I ended up just setting up some code to ForEach everything in my "include list" and chain together, ex:
displayName eq 'Deleted Items' OR displayName eq 'Junk Email'

Answer (score 0):

Found this on Microsoft documentation

List all users whose company name is either undefined or Microsoft.
GET `../users?$filter=companyName in (null, 'Microsoft')&$count=true`. This is an advanced query.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter][1]